# Using Writer to send an email with Korean text outputs garbage

Tags: java, android, writer

My app programmatically sends emails. It works when the body is English text, but when the body is Korean it comes out as garbage. For example sending '테스트' results in '???'.

Here's the code I'm using to send the email:

```
AuthenticatingSMTPClient client = new AuthenticatingSMTPClient();
    try {
        client.connect(hostname, port);
        client.ehlo("localhost");
        if (client.execTLS()) {
            client.auth(AuthenticatingSMTPClient.AUTH_METHOD.LOGIN, login, password);

            client.setSender(from);

            client.addRecipient(to);

            Writer writer = client.sendMessageData();

            if (writer != null) {
                SimpleSMTPHeader header = new SimpleSMTPHeader(from, to, subject);
                writer.write(header.toString());
                writer.write("테스트);
                writer.close();
                if (!client.completePendingCommand()) {
                    throw new Exception("Failure to sendLocation the email " + client.getReply() + client.getReplyString());
                }
            } else {
                throw new Exception("Failure to sendLocation the email " + client.getReply() + client.getReplyString());
            }
        } else {
            throw new Exception("STARTTLS was not accepted " + client.getReply() + client.getReplyString());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw e;
    } finally {
        if (client != null) {
            client.logout();
            client.disconnect();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Specify the character encoding](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/javadocs/api-3.6/org/apache/commons/net/smtp/AuthenticatingSMTPClient.html#AuthenticatingSMTPClient(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) when you create the client, e.g.

```
AuthenticatingSMTPClient client =
    new AuthenticatingSMTPClient(SMTPSClient.DEFAULT_PROTOCOL, "UTF-8");
```

Comment: Thanks that worked! I had to use `AuthenticatingSMTPClient("TLS", "UTF-8")` Edit: just saw you updated your answer to include the default protocol.